# Struggling to perform a "simple" HTTP GET using Node.js - Destination Server Using TLS 1.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, axios, http-get

I'm struggling to perform a "simple" HTTP GET using Node.js

I've done some digging, and I feel the error may stem from the Server Using TLS 1.0?

Below is a simple block of code to replicate the issue.

I'm using Node v10.9.0

```
const https = require('https');

https.get('https://supplychain.2go.com.ph', (resp) => {
    let data = '';

    resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
        data += chunk;
    });

    resp.on('end', () => {
        console.log(data);
    });

}).on("error", (err) => {
    console.log("Error: " + err.message);
});
```

The error returned is:

> Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

I have tried a number of things such as adding options:

```
rejectUnauthorized:false
```

I've also tried the same thing with **axios** and the **request** library. Both yield the same negative results.

I have no control over the sever end, so I cannot alter the TLS setting

Thank you for taking the time to read - Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you could use an old node version or connect through a proxy?

Comment: Anybody knows which is the latest node version supportin TLS 1.0? I have exactly the same trouble

Comment: This thread at github adiveces you to downgrade node (https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/21088#issuecomment-412536687), but I'm not sure which version I should try